# meteor Verifying Deployment - Connection refused

Tags: node.js, docker, meteor, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy a `meteor Application`, But I am receiving this error message on the `Verifying Deployment` section with the following error message -

```
          ------------------------------------STDERR------------------------------------
          : (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.2 port 3000: Connection refused
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
    
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
    

curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.2 port 3000: Connection refused


=> Logs:
=> Setting node version
NODE_VERSION=14.17.4
v14.17.4 is already installed.
Now using node v14.17.4 (npm v6.14.14)
default -> 14.17.4 (-> v14.17.4 *)
=> Starting meteor app on port 3000
 
=> Redeploying previous version of the app
```

When I do the `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN` in the server it shows this

```
tcp        0      0 10.0.3.1:53             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      609/dnsmasq         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      406/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      745/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      745/sshd: /usr/sbin
```

When I run `sudo docker ps` i receive the following message -

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                           PORTS     NAMES
e51b1b4bf3a3   mup-appName:latest   "/bin/sh -c 'exec $M…"   About an hour ago   Restarting (1) 49 seconds ago              appName
68b723183f3d   mongo:3.4.1           "/entrypoint.sh mong…"   9 days ago          Restarting (100) 9 seconds ago             mongodb
```

In my `firewall` i have also opened the `Port 3000`

[image]

If I check the Docker is running it seems like there is no docker running!!

[image]

Also in my `mup.js` file I am using `http` and not `https`

```
module.exports = {
  servers: {
    one: {
      host: 'xx.xx.xxx.xxx',
      username: 'ubuntu',
      pem: '/home/runner/.ssh/id_rsa'
    }
  },
  meteor: {
    name: 'appName',
    path: '../../',
    docker: {
      image: 'zodern/meteor:latest',
    },
    servers: {
      one: {}
    },
    buildOptions: {
      serverOnly: true
    },
    env: {
      PORT: 3000,
      ROOT_URL: 'http://dev-api.appName.com/',
      NODE_ENV: 'production',
      MAIL_URL: 'smtp://xxxx:xxx/eLPCB3nw3jubkq:@email-smtp.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com:587',
      MONGO_URL: 'mongodb+srv://xxx:xx@xxx.iiitd.mongodb.net/Development?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
    },
    deployCheckWaitTime: 15
  }
  proxy: {
    domains: 'dev.xxx.com',
    ssl: {
      letsEncryptEmail: 'info@xxx.com'
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea what might cause this issue?

Comment: could you post your `sudo docker ps`? mup deploys in a container. You'd want to verify that the container starts. Also, verifying deployment directly on port 3000 is a little odd. In production you almost always want to use the nginx proxy to run on port 80, and verify the deployment that way.  Did you somehow disable that proxy?

Comment: @ChristianFritz I have updated the question with the  `sudo docker ps` output, and yes I have disable the Proxy

Comment: @ChristianFritz I have now used proxy as well and still it is the same error.

Comment: did you open port 3000 in your firewall?

Comment: @ChristianFritz Yes I have open the Firewall 3000, and it's now updated with the questions with the `Inbound rules`

Comment: uh, by the way, you should *not* open port 27017 in the firewall. Unless you use passwords to protect your mongodb, anyone on the internet can now read your database.

Comment: if you don't need the proxy, then I would seriously consider going without meteor-up and just deploying the bundle created by meteor myself. There is very little value left of mup (and a lot of complexity, as you can tell).

Comment: @ChristianFritz, thank you for pointing out the MongoDB Port. Could you kindly point which bundle you are referring to deploy without meteorup and proxy here. Also, don't you think in the long run it's better to use proxy? I am now using the proxy to ensure the full potential of mup. but still receiving the same error message

Comment: @ChristianFritz, there is no docker running on the Github Action although in the meteor setup it is showing the docker is up and running but when i do `docker ps -all`it shows empty

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but in the MUP docs the correct image name is `zodern/meteor:root`

If your app is slow to start, increase the `deployCheckWaitTime` . In my complex apps I put 600, just to ensure the app is up.

Comment: thank you for the answer. Unfortunately when I use the Docker Image `roo` instead of `meteor:latest` it returns me too many errors including node and other error.